# Did I do something wrong in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I am not that good at math, but I was fooling around with some stuff, and I did this:

$$y = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\log_x(x) = \log_x(\frac{1}{y})$$
$$1 = \log_x(1) - \log_x(y)$$
$$1 + \log_x(y) = \log_x(1)$$
$$\log_x(y) = \log_x(1)- \log_x(x)$$
$$x^{\log_x(y)} = x^{\log_x(1)} - x^{\log_x(x)}$$
$$y = 1 - x$$

And this might be totally right, but it does not seem it, could someone help me find the error and explain why it is that?

EDIT:

it should be:

I understand now, I made an error! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that $\log_x(y)=\log_x(1)-\log_x(x)$ implies $x^{\log_x(y)}=x^{\log_x(1)-\log_x(x)}$ not $x^{\log_x(1)}-x^{\log_x(x)}$

Comment: OHH THAT MAKES SENSE TY

Comment: @DankaMakabre but then since $$x^{log_x(1) + log_x(x)}$$ it means that the x and the 1 are multiplied so its $$x^{log_x(1 * x)}$$ which means its $$x^{log_x(y)}$$ = x^{log_x(x)}$$ so then $$y = x$$ which isnt true?

Comment: NVM I MADE A MISTAKE

Answer (score 0):

> $$\log_x(y) = \log_x(1)- \log_x(x)$$
> $$x^{\log_x(y)} = x^{\log_x(1)} - x^{\log_x(x)}$$

This is wrong.

$$x^\text{LHS}=x^{\log_x(y)}=x^\text{RHS}=x^{\log_x(1)-\log_x(x)}\neq x^{\log_x(1)} - x^{\log_x(x)}$$